# Split mathematical string in Java

Tags: java

I have this string: "23+43*435/675-23".  How can I split it?  The last result which I want is:

```
String 1st=23
String 2nd=435
String 3rd=675
String 4th=23
```

I already used this method:

```
String s = "hello+pLus-minuss*multi/divide";
String[] split = s.split("\\+");
String[] split1 = s.split("\\-");
String[] split2 = s.split("\\*");
String[] split3 = s.split("\\/");
String plus = split[1];
String minus = split1[1];
String multi = split2[1];
String div = split3[1];
System.out.println(plus+"\n"+minus+"\n"+multi+"\n"+div+"\n");
```

But it gives me this result:

```
pLus-minuss*multi/divide
minuss*multi/divide
multi/divide
divide
```

But I require result in this form

```
pLus
minuss
multi
divide
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to skip the 43 in your input string?  Or did you just make a mistake in the list of numbers below which should list 5 numbers.

Comment: there is no particular reason here maybe any number i wanna every one in variable and than print it from variables i will be total 4 variables

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s ="23+43*435/675-23";
    String[] ss = s.split("[-+*/]");
    for(String str: ss)
        System.out.println(str);

}
```

Output:

```
23
43
435
675
23
```

I dont know why you want to store in variables and then print . Anyway try below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hello+pLus-minuss*multi/divide";
    String[] ss = s.split("[-+*/]");
    String first =ss[1];
    String second =ss[2];
    String third =ss[3];
    String forth =ss[4];

    System.out.println(first+"\n"+second+"\n"+third+"\n"+forth+"\n");

    }
```

Output:

```
pLus
minuss
multi
divide
```

Comment: It is not a good method when brackets `()` is involved. But when there is no bracket, this approach is good enough.

Comment: how can i get result in variables which u print by system.out.printlen(str); my requirment is that i wanna result in variable and than print it from variables

Comment: @hope why you want to store in other variables ? Its already stored in  String array ss.

Comment: yes . but now i have a second problem i wanna such regular exp in java for this problem 43+32.5.-32.7.9.2*22.76/23.54.7 you cane see dot is repeating i wanna that dot is allowed online one time in b/w + and - b/w two operators

Answer (score 1):

Try this out :

```
        String data = "23+43*435/675-23";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\+\\*\\/\\-]+");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group());
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
        System.out.println(index + " : " + list.get(index));
    }
```

Output :

0 : 23

1 : 43

2 : 435

3 : 675

4 : 23

Comment: i wanna result in variable like String 1st=23; String 2nd=43; etc and than i print it like System.out.println(1st+"\n"+2nd); etc

Comment: i wanna result in variables

Comment: Result that is displayed are stored in a list i.e. variable.

Comment: @hope: if you need them in variables, assign each item in list to separate variables like this:int a=list.get(0);int b=list.get(1);

Answer (score 0):

I think it is only the issue of index. You should have used index 0 to get the split result.

```
String[] split = s.split("\\+");
String[] split1 = split .split("\\-");
String[] split2 = split1 .split("\\*");
String[] split3 = split2 .split("\\/");

String hello= split[0];//split[0]=hello,split[1]=pLus-minuss*multi/divide

String plus= split1[0];//split1[0]=plus,split1[1]=minuss*multi/divide
String minus= split2[0];//split2[0]=minuss,split2[1]=multi/divide
String multi= split3[0];//split3[0]=multi,split3[1]=divide

String div= split3[1];
```

Comment: its give me this result hello
hello+pLus
hello+pLus-minuss
divide  but i wanna every one separate, not hello+pluse-minuss

Comment: Sorry. see the modified answer

Comment: But still it will work only for this particular string. You better follow other answers

Answer (score 0):

If the order of operators matters, change your code to this:

```
    String s = "hello+pLus-minuss*multi/divide";
    String[] split = s.split("\\+");
    String[] split1 = split[1].split("\\-");
    String[] split2 = split1[1].split("\\*");
    String[] split3 = split2[1].split("\\/");
    String plus = split1[0];
    String minus = split2[0];
    String multi = split3[0];
    String div = split3[1];
    System.out.println(plus + "\n" + minus + "\n" + multi + "\n" + div + "\n");
```

Otherwise, to spit on any operator, and store to variable do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "hello+pLus-minuss*multi/divide";

    String[] ss = s.split("[-+*/]");
    String plus = ss[1];
    String minus = ss[2];
    String multi = ss[3];
    String div = ss[4];
    System.out.println(plus + "\n" + minus + "\n" + multi + "\n" + div + "\n");
}
```